# Rebus implementation

Tags: message, message-queue, rebus

I have to create a POC to demonstrate that Rebus will work for this scenario -

Multiple subscribers listening to event(s) and handling them accordingly.
How can I configure this using the BuiltInContainer and the config?
Do I need to have multiple queues and multiple endpoints configured and also single instance of the container or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [the pub/sub sample](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/PubSub) that demonstrates a scenario with three separate applications, one publisher and two subscribers.

In most scenarios I recommend you create one container for each endpoint, which implies one queue per endpoint.

Comment: I do have another concern though.In an event driven system where processes are listening to various events and based upon their occurrence they do some processing.One process wants to listen to all events but the other process only to certain ones. I proposed a solution to have multiple publishers per event basis (e.g. FileDropped, Fileprocessed, FileDeleted) and then each subscriber can then subscribe to the ones they want. Does this sound like a good solution? OR  Second option to have a message filtering kind of logic where the subsciber will only receive messages that it intends to receive